# How can I implement a more realistic momentum system in Unity 4.5?

Tags: unity, physics

I'm just starting out with Unity and am making a simple environment where there is a sphere and a ramp.  When the sphere approaches the ramp everything is fine.  As soon as the sphere hits the ramp is where I'm having trouble; the velocity is instantly reduced and when it goes off the end of the ramp, instantly returns to the velocity as though it were on the ground.

I'm not sure if this can be changed by some settings in Unity or I would have to write some code.

Here's the physics code I have so far (in C#):

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;

    void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rigidbody.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for each object with a `Physics RigidBody` component you can check the Component options in the inspector... and iirc there will be check boxes and input fields to allow you to modify these values directly from the gui (`Gravity Scale, Angular Drag, Drag, etc...`).   but if you check the documentation, all of those values also represent properties of that RigidBody component.

so in theory you could grab the RigidBody of your sphere at runtime, and set the `Kinematic` property to false (stoping it from responding to physics temporarily), something like this in C#:

```
 // if you need to grab the component from another object
 sphere.GetComponent<RigidBody>().isKinematic = false;

 // or the way you have it written above is fine if this script is attached to your sphere
 rigidBody.isKinematic = false;
```

then you possibility could perform your own position calculations and when your done turn the physics back on

check out the docs here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

Comment: hope this helps if im understanding you correctly, but definitely use that documentation... tons of good stuff there

Comment: I guess the issue I'm concerned with the most is that there seems to be a discontinuous change in velocity when the shpere collides with the ramp.  Perhaps its simply the design of the ramp that is causing me to perceive this issue.  I'll play around with it more...I appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: no problem, i do believe you have a few things to look into then starting with the attributes set on the rigid bodies of both the ramp and the sphere from the GUI in the inspector. i think the Drag could be a potential culprit.  or the simulated 'friction'